# Why don't computers accept RDP connections with only a user name specified?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

If I input only an account name, without specifying the machine name, e.g. "forTest", not "computerName\forTest", the RDP client does not connect to the target machine.

After I append the "computerName\", it manages to initiate a RDP session.

The RDP client is launched by system service in session 0 as the "LocalSystem" account, interactively.

In what circumstances is inputting the computerName a must? What is a always safe way to specifying the user name in RDP client? Is it safe to always use "computerName\accountName"?

Comment: Actually I only want to connect to local machine with an local account. But it proves it is not always enough to input only the "user name".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the machine you're trying to connect is in a domain.

if you don't specify the machine name. it assumes that it's a domain user and verifies the user over the domain.

it should be same to use ".\username" which is equivalent to "computerName\accountName" but simpler.

Comment: You can use just `\username` too.